# STL Namespace Errors in fstream.h with qmake/make

Tags: c++, qt, stl, clang, qmake

I'm trying to compile my QT5 project the old school way, with `qmake && make`.  However, I'm getting unexpected errors.  There are ~20, but here's a sampling (they're all similar):

```
In file included from src/main.cc:18:
In file included from include/Ctx.h:7:
In file included from include/SrcFile.h:5:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/fstream:268:9: error:
      no template named 'has_facet'; did you mean
      '::std::has_facet'?
    if (has_facet<codecvt<char_type, char, state_...
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__locale:177:1: note:
      '::std::has_facet' declared here
has_facet(const locale& __l)  _NOEXCEPT
^
In file included from src/main.cc:18:
In file included from include/Ctx.h:7:
In file included from include/SrcFile.h:5:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/fstream:268:19: error:
      no template named 'codecvt'; did you mean
      '::std::codecvt'?
    if (has_facet<codecvt<char_type, char, state_...
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__locale:817:86: note:
      '::std::codecvt' declared here
  ...class _StateT> class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS_ONLY codecvt;
                                                ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now
      [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make: *** [tmp/main.o] Error 1
```

Below is SrcFile.h

```
#ifndef SRCFILE_H
#define SRCFILE_H

#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include "SrcObj.h"


namespace oonalysis {

class SrcFile : public SrcObj
{
public:
    SrcFile(const std::string& filename);
    std::string get_text() const;
    std::string present_name() const;
private:
    std::filebuf* get_file();
    std::string filename;
}; // class SrcFile

} // namespace oonalysis

#endif // SRCFILE_H
```

And below are the likely segments of the generated Makefile

```
INCPATH       = -I. -Iinclude -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.9.1/lib/QtWidgets.fram
ework/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.9.1/lib/QtGui.framework/Headers -I/usr
/local/Cellar/qt/5.9.1/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers -I. -I/Applications/Xcode
.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.
sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers -I/Applications/Xcode.
app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.s
dk/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.9
.1/mkspecs/macx-clang -F/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.9.1/lib
CC            = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
CXX           = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++
CXXFLAGS      = -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -g -std=gnu++1y $(EXPORT_ARCH_ARGS) -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.10 -Wall -W -fPIC $(DEFINES)
tmp/srcfile.o: src/srcfile.cc include/SrcFile.h \
                include/SrcObj.h \
                include/oonalysis.h
        $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o tmp/srcfile.o src/srcfile.cc
```

Have I misconfigured something?  Is there any way I could have two stl versions floating around?

Comment: Note: in C++ you want `#include <fstream>` *not* "fstream.h".

Comment: Thanks, I assumed the nomenclature was still fstream.h when just discussing the header in isolation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not intuitive.  In an unrelated header, `gui.h`, I hadn't closed off my namespace `gui` with an end brace.  I figured this out by commenting out `#include <fstream>` and compiling.  Now it works fine.